# how to make a set using self-defined duplicated judge function?

Tags: c++, stl, set

I want to use STL set to:

1. insert a `struct` into this set, like `struct {int id, string info};`
2. for each insert, if the id is existed, don't insert
3. make the element sorted

I tried the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
using namespace std;
struct song
{
    int m_id;
    int m_hot;
    song(int id,int hot)
    {

        this->m_id = id;
        this->m_hot = hot;
    }
    bool operator<(const struct song & right)const
    {
        if(this->m_id == right.m_id) {     // remove duplicated
            return false;
        }
        if(this->m_hot != right.m_hot)
        {
            return this->m_hot > right.m_hot;
        }
        else
        {
            return this->m_id > right.m_id;
        }
    }
};
int main()
{
    std::set<song> mySet;
    song s1(10,100);
    song s2(40,700);
    song s3(40,300);
    song s4(30,200);
    song s5(300,200);
    song s6(300,900);
    mySet.insert(s1);
    mySet.insert(s2);
    mySet.insert(s3);
    mySet.insert(s4);
    mySet.insert(s5);
    mySet.insert(s6);
    for(auto it:mySet)
    {
        std::cout<<"id:"<<it.m_id<<",hot:"<<it.m_hot<<std::endl;
    }
}
```

the output is :

> id:300,hot:900
>   id:40,hot:700
>   id:300,hot:200
>   id:30,hot:200
>   id:10,hot:100

As you can see, the id 40 removed the duplicated successfully, but 300 failed.
I think the id 300 part should not appear twice, can someone help me with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `operator<` does not satisfy [strict weak ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Strict_weak_orderings) and your requirements cannot be expressed as such.

The problem is that you have two keys, `m_id` (for uniqueness) and `m_hot` (for ordering). You can't choose to order only by `m_hot`. You always have to order (and ignore equivalent-comparing elements) by both, and you can only choose the precedence. Thus, you cannot establish equivalence between `{id=0, hot=0}` and `{id=0, hot=1}`.

<sup>^ If your comparator cannot be written as `std::tie(lhs.keys...) < std::tie(rhs.keys...)`, it's no good.</sup>

At the moment, I can only think of postponing ordering by `m_hot` at the places you need it (by copying into a `std::vector` and sorting it or inserting to a `std::set` with different comparator).